# rsync transfert no error but transfer is not happening

Tags: ssh, rsync

I want to transfer files between 2 different servers via a shell script (password less)

I set up the SSH keys following this tutorial : http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/ssh-public-key-based-authentication-how-to.html

Then i try to the transfer of a file: test.txt from server1 to server2 using this command:

```
rsync -avz /home/tasklitetest/test.txt jansia@ps27670.dreamhost.com&#58;/home/tasklite/
```

The command seems to execute without trouble because i got the following :

```
[2] 4920
[1]   Done                    rsync -avz /home/tasklitetest/test.txt jansia@ps27670.dreamhost.com
[ps115171]$ sending incremental file list

sent 62 bytes  received 12 bytes  148.00 bytes/sec
total size is 396  speedup is 5.35
```

But i got not file on my other server in /home/tasklite/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the server you're connecting to actually impossibly named "ps27670.dreamhost.com:" or is that supposed to be a ":" that got munged in your copy/paste?  The error message you're getting suggests that you have a stray "&" that's telling the shell to put the rsync command into the background.

If this is the case, clean up your command and try again.  You probably want this:

```
rsync -avz /home/tasklitetest/test.txt jansia@ps27670.dreamhost.com:/home/tasklite/
```

Comment: As a side note, you likely have a file named "jansia@ps27670.dreamhost.com" in the directory you ran the rsync command.  Basically, what happened is that you copied the file `/home/tasklitetest/test.txt` to a new file `jansia@ps27670.dreamhost.com`.  You only designate a remote host by putting ":" after the hostname, and specifying the remote target.

Comment: ah ok i will check that i didn't know for the : i'll not forget now thanks!

Comment: yes you were right ;)